# Bolt-js in socket mode on heroku fails with Error R10

Tags: heroku, slack, slack-api, bolt

I have a slack bolt-js server app that runs with socketMode: true
It works perfectly fine on my local pc, but when moving it to Heroku in a web dyno, it fails after 1 min. It starts up just fine and it is fully functional during that minute, but after 1 min I get this

```
2021-09-01T12:59:33.771745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

My bolt-js app is started like this:

```
await app.start(process.env.PORT);
```

I think Heroku is failing to detect that there is a websocket on this port open and then times out.

I went through a lot of documentation already. I must say that the bolt-js documentation is conflicting with Heroku's. They suggest I use a worker dyno, but Heroku says explicitly that worker dynos cannot receive web HTTP traffic.

Totally at a loss here. Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this just a few days ago, I found that changing the dyno type on Heroku from `web` to `worker` solved this issue. The idea came [from this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos), specifically the `Dyno configurations` section.

To change the dyno type, navigate to the `Resources` section of your Heroku app, you should see something like the following:
[Resources Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvJVk.png)

From there you want to edit the `web` type and toggle it off -- do the same for the `worker` type and toggle it on. The dyno automatically restarts so you should be able to view the logs immediately.

Comment: This helped me so much, I had been messing around with all kinds of settings.

Answer (score 0):

This question is posted far log ago but may be this help to anyone.
you can add port in app configuration like

```
const {App} = require('@slack/bolt');
const app = new App({
    token:process.env.bot_token,
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
});
(async()=>{
await app.start();
})
```

may be this help to you.